# How to include dynamic Javascript file in the DOM without repeating same file

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to load `<div>` content dynamically by using AJAX in a specific div. After the AJAX call I want to load a JS file in the footer. I loaded content by clicking menu without page loading by using URL hash. My problem is when I click the same link multiple times, the JS file is loading multiple times because the JS file is appended. That's why every event occurs multiple times. I want to load the JS file before checking if the file is already loaded into the DOM. If the file is not loaded in the DOM, I will append a JS file in the DOM.

As the answer suggested by this [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file/950146#950146), here is my code:

```
var Utils = {
  loadjs: function(url){
    var footer = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;
    footer.appendChild(script);
  },
}
Utils.loadjs(url);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can read the script tags to search for a particular script is there or not. Something like below:

```js
var Utils = {
  loadjs: function(url) {
    var me = document.querySelectorAll('script[src="' + url + '"]');
    if (me && me.length >= 1) {
      return null;
    }
    var footer = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;
    footer.appendChild(script);
  },
}
Utils.loadjs(url);
```

Comment: I got error in me.length line. error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Comment: I checked your code. but when I use console.log(me.length), it returned undefined

Comment: Can You try now.

Comment: Yes. I tried. the code gives output when I use  if (me) return null

Comment: didnot get you, Does that answer your question?

Comment: In your answer I use if (me ) instead of if (me && me.length >= 1), then answer is working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219879/discussion-between-asutosh-and-alien).

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic `import()` syntax to load modules, even from regular scripts.

This has the benefit of loading those scripts as modules, which are always in strict mode and have module scope.

[Read more about dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports)

So, instead of `Utils.loadjs(url)`, just `import(url)`